# how to know how many device connectd to sqlserver remotly

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

hello i have a program linked with mysql server remotly
i want to know devices connected number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely you can count devices, however there is a system table information_schema.processlist which shows MySQL server process list, you can count hosts there. See [details here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-processlist-table.html) on required privileges and fields.